# Call value from another node xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, transformation

I need some tip here to finish the solution, imagine the (EDIT XML just for show propose) below:

```
<root>
<header>
  <Document>
      ... many tags
  <Document>
  <extension>
     <flag>X</flag>
  </extension>
</header>
<body> 
   <List> 
      <Object>
         ... many tags
        <extension>
         ... many tags
        </extension>
      </Object>
      <Event>
         ... many tags
        <extension>
          ... many tags
        </extension>
      </Event>
   </List>
</body>
```

I have this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Event">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
                <xsl:if test="header/extension[flag = 
                  'X']">
                DO SOMETHING
                </if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//Object" />
```

What the program must do is IF ( the tag (flag) from (header) contains X) do something inside the template match=Event.

I already try:  header/extension[flag ='X'] and ../extension/flag = 'X' and header/extension/flag = 'X'

it's not working properly.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current expression is relative to the current `Event` node, and `header` is not a child of the `EventNode`.

You need to make the expression relative to the "document" node, so effectively it is an absolute path

```
<xsl:if test="/root/header/extension[flag = 'X']">
```

(And obviously you need to correct your XSLT as you currently have a closing `</if>` tag, rather than `<xsl:if>`)

Rather than evaluate the same path for each `Event` though, you might consider storing the result in a globally available variable

```
 <xsl:variable name="extension" select="/root/header/extension[flag = 'X']" />
```

Then you can just do this...

```
<xsl:if test="$extension">
```

Comment: now I understand what I did wrong. but what means [ ] , i think I can´t make globally variable, because this <flag> can contains others values, X was just sample but I did poc here and works. Thanks for the tip ! ;)

Comment: You could define the variable `<xsl:variable name="extension" select="/root/header/extension/flag" />` and then your if statement could be `<xsl:if test="$extension = 'X' or $extension = 'Y'" />`. Or in XSLT 2.0 you could do `<xsl:if test="$extension=('X', 'Y')" />`